# Put URL to Firebase Storage file into variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to put the URL of my image into a variable so I can log the URL from the image to the console. I don't know why, but every time I try to do that it just doesn't log anything (and also gives no error). This is the way I'm trying it now:

```js
}, function() {
  // The file is done uploading to Firebase Storage
  let url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
  console.log(url)
}
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong and I know this is probably not the hardest thing to figure out, but I really can't find it. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can access `downloadURL` like:

```
task.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
  //....
}, function(error) {
  // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
  // Handle successful uploads on complete
  task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});
```

Comment: @palasH, that still doesn't work, the only thing that i'm getting in the console is this: [image on imgur.com](https://imgur.com/a/RbYRdap)

Comment: Not sure why it din't work. As per [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress) that is the way to do it. Can you put a `debugger` keyword above `uploadTask.snapshot.ref ....` code and see what values are you getting for `uploadTask`, `uploadTask.snapshot.ref` and also put a debugger inside `.then` to see if it is going inside or not.

Comment: I've put a debugger into both of them, this is what I get: https://imgur.com/a/EK7AI0r

Comment: @Rune: This is the correct way of getting the download URL. The syntax you use to get a download URL hasn't been valid for almost two years. If you're still having problems after using this code, post a new question with a minimal, complete/standalone reproduction of the problem, as right now there's not enough for use to troubleshoot with. Also consider setting up a reproduction on a site like jsbin, so we can have a look.

Comment: @Rune After using `debugger` you need to build you project if needed, then reload the page and then in browser console you will most probably jump to the "Sources" tab.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is my full JavaScript code: https://jsfiddle.net/feLp40qm/1/

Comment: @Rune try the updated code. The issue was that you were using `task` variable instead of `uploadTask`.